# Declare a variable for use later in the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to understand how I can declare a variable that I can use later on in my jquery code. Below I am trying to use `var id` but it seems to be forgotten by the time I try to use it in an `alert(id)`. How can I do this? Many thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {

   //Declare variables

    var id = ($(this).prop("value"));
    var test_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

    //Load modal
    $('.modal-container').load('modalbox.php?id=' + id, '&position_id=' + test_id,
      function() {
        $('#myModal').modal({
          show: true
        });
      }
    );
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function() {

    alert(id); //Var id is lost.

  });
}); //close doc
```

Comment: It´s the scope of the variable that is the problem. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare `var id` publically instead of inside that `$('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {` and you are done.

Your current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {

       //Declare variables

        var id = ($(this).prop("value"));
        var test_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

        //Load modal
        $('.modal-container').load('modalbox.php?id=' + id, '&position_id=' + test_id,
          function() {
            $('#myModal').modal({
              show: true
            });
          }
        );
      });

      $(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function() {

        alert(id); //Var id is lost.

      });
    });
```

Change to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var id;
$('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {

   //Declare variables

    id = ($(this).prop("value"));
    var test_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

    //Load modal
    $('.modal-container').load('modalbox.php?id=' + id, '&position_id=' + test_id,
      function() {
        $('#myModal').modal({
          show: true
        });
      }
    );
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function() {

    alert(id); //Var id is lost.

  });
});
```

Comment: This gives me alert that says undefined.

Comment: @JulianJ are you sure? Seems there is some other issue. Above will work

Comment: @JulianJ If you click on the `.myBtn` before the `.credit_btn` it will be `undefined`. If that is not the case, provide a code snippet that actually reproduce the issue

Comment: As .myBtn is within a modal I can't click on it first. I'm test code now.

Comment: @JulianJ With the given code sample this answer works. If your `$(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function() {..}` is not within the `$(document).ready(function() {...}` it won't though, and if, your `var id;` needs to be outside it.

Comment: change `alert(id); //Var id is lost.` to `alert($('.credit_btn').prop('value'));`

Comment: Yes, it all works. My mistake I was still using var id rather than just id to declare the variable. Many thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

As with all lexical scoping, declare `id` in a block such that everywhere it's used is in the same block or a descendant block:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id;
  $('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {
    id = ($(this).prop("value"));
    var test_id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    //Load modal
    $('.modal-container').load('modalbox.php?id=' + id, '&position_id=' + test_id, function() {
      $('#myModal').modal({
        show: true
      });
    });
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".myBtn", function() {
    alert(id);
  });
}); //close doc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare the variable outside of callback function scope then use it inside the callback function

```
 $( function() {
 var id;
 $('.credit_btn').on('click', function() {
   id=1;
 })

 } );
```